# I want to add JSON-LD articles, to the blogger template

Tags: blogger, json-ld

On the internet I got this code from below Json-LD Article, but I do not know what code I have to add in the fields:

```
[Article title]
[Article sub heading]
[Main article image url]
[Author name]
[Date in ISO format e.g. 2014-03-16]
[Article summary]
```

Nor I know, in which part of the template I have to put. I do not know anything about programming.

Please can you help me put the json-ld article, in the [contempo blogger](http://www.catalogosmx.moda) template

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{ 
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Article",
  "headline": "[article title]",
  "alternativeHeadline": "[article sub heading]",
  "image": "[main article image url]",
  "author": "[author name]",
  "datePublished": "[date in ISO format e.g. 2014-03-16]",
  "description": "[article summary]"
}
</script>
```

Comment: Didn’t the page you got this code from have instructions? Can you link to it?

Comment: How could I link it, please, could you help me?

Comment: I mean the page you got the code from. Just [edit] your question and paste the URL, like you also linked "contempo blogger".

Comment: Okay, now edit and I put the page

Comment: Ah, that’s your site, I guess? Then we misunderstood. I meant the source of the code you show in your question (you said "On the internet I got this code […]").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the new themes released by Blogger ( like the Contempo theme you are using ), they have included a new data tag for automatically generating the JSON-LD data of a post. The tag responsible for this is -

```
<b:include data='post' name='postMetadataJSON'/>
```

It generates the following data by default -

```
<script type='application/ld+json'>
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "BlogPosting",
    "mainEntityOfPage": {
        "@type": "WebPage",
        "@id": "POST-URL"
    },
    "headline": "POST TITLE",
    "description": "POST SNIPPET",
    "datePublished": "DATE-PUBLISHED",
    "dateModified": "DATE-MODIFIED",
    "image": {
        "@type": "ImageObject",
        "url": "IMAGE-URL",
        "height": 630,
        "width": 1200
    },
    "publisher": {
        "@type": "Organization",
        "name": "Blogger",
        "logo": {
            "@type": "ImageObject",
            "url": "BLOGGER-LOGO",
            "width": 206,
            "height": 60
        }
    },
    "author": {
        "@type": "Person",
        "name": "AUTHOR NAME"
    }
}
</script>
```

This tag is by default included in all new themes, therefore you will not have to add it from your side.

Comment: Hello Unor and Prayag.
Indeed, the new themes bring JSON-LD data by default, but I wanted to include for a better SEO the JSON-LD Article.

Tell me, it is advisable to do what I want or I have to leave the basic data provided by blogger.

What is the best thing for a better SEO on my website?

I think that in blogger can not be added enriched cards?

I hope your help .. and thanks for your time

Comment: @JhonnySanz all the data that you wanted to include is already present in the default tag provided by Blogger. Also, BlogPosting is a specialized type of Article ( Refer to https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/46680/using-schema-org-for-blogging-article-vs-blogposting ) so there is not much difference between them. The tag included by Blogger covers all the basic information related to an article. What extra information do you require to add to the JSON-LD data?

Answer (score 0):

You can make with custom theme by placing code right after `<b:includable id='post' var='post'>`

```
<b:includable id='post' var='post'>
<script type='application/ld+json'>
  <-- ld json content -->
</script>
<-- other code -->
```

example

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{ "@context": "http://schema.org", 
 "@type": "BlogPosting",
 "headline": "<data:post.title/>",
 "alternativeHeadline": "<data:post.title/>",
 "mainEntityOfPage" : "<data:blog.homepageUrl/>",
 "image": {
     "@type" : "imageObject",
     "url" : "<data:post.firstImageUrl/>",
     "height": "480",
     "width": "720"
 },
 "publisher": {
     "@type" : "organization",
    "name" : "Organization Name",
    "logo": {
        "@type" : "imageObject",
        "url" : "http://logo-url.png"
    }
 },
 "url": "<data:post.url.canonical/>",
 "datePublished": "<data:post.timestampISO8601/>",
 "dateCreated": "<data:post.timestampISO8601/>",
 "dateModified": "<data:post.timestampISO8601/>",
 "description": "<data:blog.metaDescription/>",
 "articleBody":"<data:post.body.jsonEscaped/>",
   "author": {
    "@type": "Person",
    "name": "<data:post.author/>"
  }
 }
</script>
```

look at [This Article](https://bloggerbook.blakbin.com/2018/10/make-valid-ld-json-for-every-blogger.html) for detailed instruction.